# Screen Size and Image Aren't Functioning Correctly

Tags: java, dimension

As I final for my Computer Sciences class we could either teach a lesson in Java or some sort of big project.  I used an existing pokemon java engine and am building my game around that. The problem that I am running into is that it isn't the correct size (160,144) and the image won't show up unless you re-size the frame. If anyone has any ideas why that'd be great. Also the paths for the pictures are correct it just won't let me post them for some reason.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AnotherIdea {

public static class Engine extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    public static JFrame jf;
    public Toolkit tk = jf.getToolkit();
    private Image titlescreen = tk.createImage("F:\\Votech Final\\Welcome to Nightvale\\anotherIdea\\src\\Resources\\Tittle.png");
    private Image start_symbol = tk.createImage("F:\\Votech Final\\Welcome to                                                              Nightvale\\anotherIdea\\src\\Resources\\Start.png");
    private boolean atTitle = true;
    private boolean atContinueScreen = false;
    private boolean start_visible = true;
    private boolean gamestarted = false;
    private int offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
private int TILE_WIDTH_PIXELS = 32;
private int TILE_HEIGHT_PIXELS = 32;
private int concurrentMenuItem = 0;
public long seconds = 0;
public long oldTime;
public long minutes = 0;
public long hours = 0;



public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    g2.setTransform(at);
    if (atTitle == true) {
        g.drawImage(titlescreen,0,0,null);
        if (start_visible == true) {
            g.drawImage(start_symbol,0,260,null);
        }
}
}
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (atTitle == true) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            atTitle = false;                
}
}
}
public static void main(String [] Args) {
     //Create the window
     jf = new JFrame("T.I.N.");
     jf.setSize(160,144);
     //Create an instance of Pokemon and insert into the window
     Engine engine = new Engine();
     jf.add(engine);
     jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     jf.setResizable(true);
     jf.pack();
     //Center the Game on the Screen
     Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
     int w = jf.getSize().width;
     int h = jf.getSize().height;
     int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
             int y = (dim.height-h)/2;
     jf.setLocation(x,y);
     //Set focus to the Panel
     jf.setVisible(true);
     engine.requestFocus(true);                 

 }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of     generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
}
```

`

Comment: You'd have to be far more explicit than simply throw us the bible of code and give us the surface of the situation. What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: After adding the JFrame I tried putting the stuff like setResizable, pack, and setVisible down to the bottom. Also I tried adding in jf.setSize and it would set it to the correct size but then it wouldn't update with the image on it and etc.

Also I'm sorry, I'm pretty sure the problem is down in the main method. But I didn't want to leave any part out.

Comment: It's fine, you seem to be new around here. Try out David Coler's solution. I had some similar issue a long time ago and it went around the same way. Tell us how it goes.

Comment: I am. I've always been told to avoid Stack Overflow, but I need help and it doesn't seem so bad.
When I added jf.setPreferredSize(160,144); I got this error:
 "method setPreferredSize in class Component cannot be applied to give types; required:Dimension found:int,int"

Comment: It requires you to pass a `Dimension` like so, `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 144));`. Tell me if that gives you your desired behaviour.

Comment: Alright, that seems to have fixed the problem with the sizing, thank you so much.
But now about the image. Now if I set Resizable to true once I resize the window the image shows up, but just running to application it does not.

Comment: I'm having difficulty grasping the second part of your problem. What do you mean, setting resizeable to true once you resize the window? Resizeable must be true from the start to do that. Your image it probably too big to show up which explains why it will only show up when you resize the window. However I'm not sure if that's the case

Comment: I will try that when I get back to my computer tonight, thank you.

Comment: Even resizing the panel to something way too big like 200,200 doesn't work.